# Why was this question marked off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Just wanted to ask why this was marked off-topic?

[How do I learn to program or code so that I can contribute to the community?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284049/how-do-i-learn-to-program-or-code-so-that-i-can-contribute-to-the-community)

I agree that it may depend on how you read the question, but I read it as the user wanted to contribute to the Ubuntu community.

And it may be a little disengaging to have the topic closed with no further explanation.

Answer (score 9):

Because it is clearly off topic: it isn't a question about Ubuntu at all. The OP is looking for a *person* who can help them learn. That's absolutely great, and I wish the OP the very best, but that isn't a question that we can answer.

Even if we don't take it literally, the best we could do is offer some sort of list of resources. This is also off topic since it isn't a technical question about Ubuntu but is asking for off-site resources.

In any case, the question itself wasn't related to Ubuntu at all. It was about learning to program. So it really isn't even close to being on topic here. In all, I don't really see how we could have done anything other than close it.

Remember that we're trying to keep things short and to the point here. This site is *not* a forum, and the reason it works is precisely because we only do direct, questions and answers about Ubuntu. So this sort of broad, open ended question, which isn't even Ubuntu-related, is not the sort of thing we handle here. That's what the Ubuntu Forums and the dozens of other sites that allow discussions are for!

Comment: I agree it was very open ended and not specific to Ubuntu. All I suggested was maybe just an explanation for the OP as to why it was closed.

Comment: @ArturMeinild sure, you could leave a comment explaining. That would be friendly. But the question is as blatantly off topic as it gets, really.